# How to sort data.frame in a function

Tags: r, sorting

This code works:

```
df_sorted_1 <- df[with(df,
  do.call("order", list(name, value))
),]
```

I want to sort, based on the `"name"` and `"value"` columns.

But when I tried to create a function for this:

```
sort_df <- function (df, sort_vars) {
  df_sorted <- df[with(df,
    do.call("order", sort_vars)
),]

df_sorted <- sort_df(df, list("name", "value"))
```

I have no idea why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R` wants a `name` object, so next code solves my issue:

```
sort_df <- function (df, sort_vars) {
  df_sorted <- df[with(df,
    do.call("order", lapply(sort_vars, as.name))
),]

df_sorted <- sort_df(df, list("name", "value"))
```

Comment: What about simply `orderMeAround <- function(inDF, ...) inDF[with(inDF, do.call(order, inDF[c(...)])), ]`. You can then just use it like `orderMeAround(df, "name", "value")`.